# Stitching sub images to reconstruct original image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

Assume that we have an image which splitted into 4 sub images vertically. After split, we shuffle the sub images. How can I get original image from sub images? OR, how we can correctly sort the sub images to get original one even we do not know the order?
[image]

[image]

(Edit) Solution: To recognize transition points first you can check the pixel difference on X axis. After getting transition points, you can divide image into sub images. Now, you can compare & sort right pixels and lefts pixels of each sub images.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Ideally, you would avoid shuffling them so I presume there's some aspect that is missing from your question.

Comment: I have cropped & shuffled sub images. I have to sticth them to get original one.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I am trying to understand *why* you shuffled them if you didn't want to. That might lead to an understanding of *how* and *what* you used to shuffle them and that might lead to an easy way of re-assembling them.

Comment: To find the right order you could check for vertical edges at the border between subimages and test this in every possible order/pair. When there is s smooth transition from one subimage to the next there shouldn't be many such edges.

Comment: @Mark Setchell In fact, I am challenging myself to solve image processing problems. You can think like stitching in a panorama.

Comment: The simplest initial approach is probably to take the left and right edges of each image and difference the edge with the others and find the pairs of edges with the least summed absolute differences.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you split your image, one solution is saving the original index/location with the image in a tuple. Once they get shuffled, you can then sort the list of images based off this index getting back the original order. Then use `hconcat` to stitch them together.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
img_list = []
# split image in half
img_B = img_list.append((1, img[:, img.shape[1]//2:]))
img_A = img_list.append((0, img[:, :img.shape[1]//2]))
# img_list is in order 1, 0
sorted_list = sorted(img_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
# sorted to correct order of 0, 1

result = cv2.hconcat([sorted_list[0][1], sorted_list[1][1]])
```

Comment: Assume that you do not know the order.

Comment: @dasmehdix this seems impossible if you have no idea about the order... you would have to match features in the images somehow, maybe add an overlap for the patches.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you know the order of the image splits, you could join them back using hconcat()

```
# horizontally concatenates images
# of same height 
im_h = cv2.hconcat([imgA, imgB])    

# show the output image
cv2.imshow('man_image.jpeg', im_h)
```

Comment: What I mean is how can we sort these splits correctly? I am not asking about concatting sub-images